# How can I make a favicon stay static?

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey, favicon

I'd like to prevent the favicon from changing on Firefox on my Mac.

I'm thinking that I might be able to do it with Grease Monkey.

My goal is to prevent things like Slack from changing the Favicon to indicate there's a notification.

Can I tell websites that they must use the same favicon they loaded with without changing it?

Comment: Did you check for some extension [such as this one]https://addons.mozilla.org/en-CA/firefox/addon/favicon-customizer/?src=search) among the others. You can set for an url a custom icon/image that can be the original one too Iif you donwload... BTW It is difficult that a general solution may exists. For a specific site/version maybe. I do not remember if the above addon works on subpages too (example.com/*) or only on a defined url, but it is not the only one working on favicons.

Comment: I bet that I can do something like this with Grease Monkey, but I don't know how

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a Greasemonkey script that uses a Javascript [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe) to observe when the favicon changes and then change it back immediately before you notice anything.

Here is how to do this:

1. If you haven't done so already, install the [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/?src=search) Firefox extension (this question is about Firefox, but you can also do this on Chrome and Edge by using the Tampermonkey extension: [link for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo), [link for Edge](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/tampermonkey/iikmkjmpaadaobahmlepeloendndfphd?hl=en-US))
2. Click on the Greasemonkey menu in the top bar, then select "New user script..." (if you're using Tampermonkey, the button is called "Create a new script...")

   [image]
3. When you've clicked on that button, it should open a new tab with a big text area where you can write Javascript code. The text area will probably already have some code in it. Simply delete that code and replace it with this:

   ```
   // ==UserScript==
   // @name         Do not change the favicon
   // @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
   // @version      0.1
   // @description  Prevents sites from changing the favicon
   // @author       You
   // @match        http://*/*
   // @match        https://*/*
   // @grant        none
   // ==/UserScript==

   (function() {
       'use strict';

       //Initialize some variables
       var favicon = document.querySelector("link[rel='shortcut icon']");
       const initialIcon = favicon.href;

       //Define the function to run when the favicon changes
       var observer = new MutationObserver(function(){
           if(favicon.href != initialIcon){
               favicon.href = initialIcon;    //Change the favicon back directly when it changes before you notice anything
           }
       });

       //Run the function above whenever the favicon changes
       observer.observe(favicon, {attributes: true});
   })();
   ```

   The lines on the top that start with `//` define properties of the script. `@name` defines the name of the script, and `@match` defines on which sites the script should be run (`http://*/*` and `https://*/*` means all sites).

   The part on the bottom is the actual script with keeps the favicon from changing. As I explained in the beginning of my answer, what it does is it detects when the favicon changes and quickly changes it back before you notice anything.
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save the script, and then you should be done.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working for me

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to edit the cookie tied to the site/web app and change the value that allows notification. There are extensions like CookieCutter that allow you to edit cookies although that one is for Safari.

Comment: It's perfectly possible for sites to change the favicon dynamically without setting a cookie. While some sites might set cookies to decide whether or not to change the favicon, in general the two are unrelated.